# ckeditor turn off enter key

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to use ckeditor to edit single lines so I don't want users to be able to use the enter key.  Does anyone know how to stop the enter key from being used?

I tried `$("#text").keypress(function(event){ alert(event.keyCode); });` But it didn't register.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did. I created a dummy plugin called 'doNothing'. Just create a 'doNothing' directory under 'plugins', then paste the following code into a plugin.js file there.

```
(function()
{
    var doNothingCmd =
    {
        exec : function( editor )
        {
            return;
        }
    };
    var pluginName = 'doNothing';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( pluginName,
    {
        init : function( editor )
        {
            editor.addCommand( pluginName, doNothingCmd );
        }
    });
})();
```

Add the plugin to your config.js file with `config.extraPlugins = 'doNothing';`, then put in

```
config.keystrokes =
[
    [ 13 /*Enter*/, 'doNothing'],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 121 /*F10*/, 'toolbarFocus' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 122 /*F11*/, 'elementsPathFocus' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 121 /*F10*/, 'contextMenu' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90 /*Z*/, 'undo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 89 /*Y*/, 'redo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 90 /*Z*/, 'redo' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76 /*L*/, 'link' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /*B*/, 'bold' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73 /*I*/, 'italic' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 /*U*/, 'underline' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 109 /*-*/, 'toolbarCollapse' ]
];
```

Voila! Now the enter key does absolutely nothing. You should also be able assign 'doNothing' to any other key you want to disable, though I haven't tried others myself.

Answer (score 4):

CKEditor 4 has a [`blockedKeystrokes`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-blockedKeystrokes) property available on the config object.

Example that blocks enter and shift+enter:

```
CKEDITOR.inline('someEditorElementId', {
    blockedKeystrokes: [13, CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 13]
});
```

Comment: `blockedKeystrokes` is not working for me on ckeditor **4.7.3**, unless I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a hack, but the way I got it to work was to change what happens on the keystroke config. I set it to 'blur'.

```
keystrokes:
   [
   [ 13, 'blur'],
   [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 13, 'blur' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90, 'undo' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 89, 'redo' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 90, 'redo' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66, 'bold' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73, 'italic' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 , 'underline' ],
   [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 109, 'toolbarCollapse' ]
   ]
```

Also, before the data is posted, I remove any of the paragraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution either (the regex could be too simple as well, but I'm lucky in that I'm not allowing source mode). Would be nice if it just rejected the key if you did a return false from a key event.

```
    $('#text').ckeditorGet().on('afterCommandExec', function (e) {
    var text = $('#text').ckeditorGet().getData();
    $('#text').ckeditorGet().setData(text.replace(/<\/*p>/i, ''));
    $('#text').ckeditorGet().focus();
});
```

It would need to be combined with config.shiftEnterMode to CKEDITOR.ENTER_P or you'd have to handle br's as well. the focus is not perfect either as it resets the cursor position. Using afterCommandExec seems to be an event fired after the enter key has been pressed, in the absence of a keyup (for a sort-of keyup, see [the onchange plugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html))

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you have is that the ckeditor uses as iframe for the editing part and events (like the key events) don't bubble out of an iframe like they do for normal elements.

The way I did it was to wire up to the ckeditor's key event and cancel it for enter. Something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace($('#myText')[0], //can't be jQuery obj
{ on: {'key': ckeditorKeyPress} }
);

function ckeditorKeyPress(event){
    switch(event.data.keyCode){
      case 13: //enter key
        event.cancel();
        event.stop();
      break;
    }
    //trigger an imitation key event here and it lets you catch the enter key
    //outside the ckeditor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the plugin or the blocked key strokes to work, so I handled this by capturing the key event.

Note: inspired by this [comment](https://ckeditor.com/old/comment/61195#comment-61195)

```
editor.on('key', function(e) {
    if (e.data.keyCode === 13 /*enter*/ ||
        e.data.keyCode === 2228237 /*shift + enter*/) {
            e.cancel();
    }
}
```